# Help creating an INSERT INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert-statement

I am inserting rows into SQL Server 2005 from PowerShell. I need to add a WHERE NOT EXISTS clause to my code to stop inserting duplicates. I am testing the SQL code in SSMS and cannot get it to work.

Where is the mistake in the following code?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PrptyValSrce
    (PrptySrceName, PrptyNameSrce, PrptyValSrce, PrptyTS) 
VALUES
    (@property, @propertyDesc, @value, @Timestamp)
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * from PrptyValSrce as b
 WHERE b.Seqno
 AND b.PrptySrceName = @property
 AND b.PrptyNameSrce = @propertyDesc
 AND b.PrptyValSrce = @value
 AND b.PrptyTS = @Timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is invalid - you can't have a `WHERE` clause applied to `VALUES`. Try this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
     SELECT * 
     from PrptyValSrce as b
     WHERE b.Seqno
         AND b.PrptySrceName = @property
         AND b.PrptyNameSrce = @propertyDesc
         AND b.PrptyValSrce = @value
         AND b.PrptyTS = @Timestamp)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.PrptyValSrce
        (PrptySrceName, PrptyNameSrce, PrptyValSrce, PrptyTS) 
        VALUES
        (@property, @propertyDesc, @value, @Timestamp)
    END
```

Comment: darn - beat me by 13 seconds.... but that BEGIN...END pair really isn't needed... (just to be nit-picky <grin>)

Comment: Thank you very much, couldn't understand why the select.. where not exists worked and the insert into... didn't

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do an `INSERT....VALUES` and add a `WHERE` clause to that. If you do `INSERT...VALUES`, those values get inserted - period.

You need to change around the way you do your check:

```
IF NOT EXISTS((SELECT * from PrptyValSrce as b
 WHERE b.Seqno
 AND b.PrptySrceName = @property
 AND b.PrptyNameSrce = @propertyDesc
 AND b.PrptyValSrce = @value
 AND b.PrptyTS = @Timestamp)
     INSERT INTO dbo.PrptyValSrce
        (PrptySrceName, PrptyNameSrce, PrptyValSrce, PrptyTS) 
     VALUES
        (@property, @propertyDesc, @value, @Timestamp)
```

Do a `IF NOT EXISTS` check, and if that succeeds, then do you `INSERT....VALUES`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PrptyValSrce
    (PrptySrceName, PrptyNameSrce, PrptyValSrce, PrptyTS) 
SELECT @property, @propertyDesc, @value, @Timestamp
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * from PrptyValSrce as b
 WHERE b.Seqno
 AND b.PrptySrceName = @property
 AND b.PrptyNameSrce = @propertyDesc
 AND b.PrptyValSrce = @value
 AND b.PrptyTS = @Timestamp);
```